# Understanding mytop display to monitor mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

I am new to using MySQL monitoring tools. I just installed mytop and innotop as recommended by many as good MySQL monitoring tools. However, i am not sure how to make sense of the info they display when you run the tools. Below is what gets displayed when i run mytop:

MySQL on localhost (10.0.13-MariaDB-log)                                                                                                                                                                                                     up 4+20:06:03 [09:12:43]
 Queries: 197.0  qps:    0 Slow:     0.0         Se/In/Up/De(%):    00/00/00/00 
             qps now:    0 Slow qps: 0.0  Threads:    3 (   3/   0) 00/00/00/00 
 Key Efficiency: 100.0%  Bps in/out:   0.0/  3.0   Now in/out:   8.3/ 2.5k

```
  Id      User         Host/IP         DB      Time    Cmd Query or State                                                                                                                                                                                        
  --      ----         -------         --      ----    --- ----------                                                                                                                                                                                            
  10 superuser       localhost                    0  Query show full processlist                                                                                                                                                                                 
   6 ashcloud_   192.168.9.142               414409 Binlog Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated                                                                                                                                 
   4 ashcloud_   192.168.9.143               417934 Binlog Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated
```

How can i interpret this to know if my server is running good or not?

**Innotop results:**

```
Uptime  MaxSQL  ReplLag  Cxns  Lock  QPS   QPS     Run  Run     Tbls  Repl   SQL
4d                      3     0  0.40  ^_____       ______    70  Off 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with the man page:  http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/mytop.html#the display

mytop is showing that nothing is running, except replication to two different servers.

If your database is idle, or your queries are returning quickly enough, then you're OK for now.